# how to use mutex for a simple distributed counter / id gen with minimal performance hit

Tags: database, nosql, distributed-computing

I would like to setup a simple auto-incrementing id using a nosql database that doesn't support this feature and was considering handling this using a mutex to guarantee ordering. I was concerned about the performance implications of this and was considering using a queue as a way to make it non-blocking. I feel like this is a very common problem with things like youtube view counts or facebook like counts but perhaps they're using something built into the dbms with sql. I was wondering if anyone can confirm that this is ok or if there's an already canonical solution to this problem with the constraints I mentioned. Thanks!